# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE issue with special characters

Tags: mysql, utf-8, special-characters

Im having problems with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE loading a utf8 file.
The Query looks like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE artikel CHARACTER SET UTF8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

But fields with special characters like "Dämmung" will be cut to "D".

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%_set_%';
```

Shows that it's all set to utf8, and I even used notepad++ to make sure the file is utf8.

It would really help, if someone knows advice, it's a huge file and I would like to avoid entering the wrong fields manually :-/

Comment: You need to set the connection, database, table and column encodings to the same character set as the data was saved in the CSV file.

Comment: @SathishD: No, you don't -- but even if you did, the OP states that all character set variables are already set to utf8.  Though if the column encoding *does not support all characters in the file* (need not be the same encoding as the file), data may well be truncated.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers! The cause was my select query, which didn't update the table correctly, so the query above is correct. Sry guys, my fault

Comment: I just get the same problem. Command exactly the same like above. However, all French characters always get truncated, leaving the data become incomplete. The CSV file is already UTF-8, table collation is utf8_general_ci.

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same problem. 
There is a "hack" that solves this: maitain everything with UTF8. The exception is with the "LOAD DATA LOCAL....". When I use LATIN1 instead of UTF8 it works fine.

Answer (score 6):

It worked for me.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:/File.csv'
INTO TABLE my_table
CHARACTER SET latin1 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution when I was troubleshooting this problem of a special characters:

I will explain:

- you can change `;` to `,` because I used csv `;` separated not like you
- I had line breaks inside my columns so I escaped with \\

The script is :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:/File.csv'
INTO TABLE my_table
CHARACTER SET latin1 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `LOAD DATA` does not accept utf8 input, no matter what charset is passed on cli options and used by the table. I didn't find it in documentation and assume it is a bug.

The workaround is to use [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html#option_mysqlimport_login-path) instead. The shortcoming of this solution is that if you want to disable foreign key check during import (doesn't apply to MyISAM tables) you will have to disable it globally, which requires SUPER privilege:

```
echo "SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" | mysql -u root -p
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take care about the collation type of the database and table columns!

I'm using the `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` for both database and table columns.

Everything worked well with keeping `CHARACTER SET utf8` in the query.